# Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools compiler with Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio, build-tools

Recently I decided to move from Microsoft Visual Studio to Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools. I am working with the latest Eclipse and want to utilize the Microsoft C++ compiler.

While having Microsoft Visual Studio installed there was an option to choose the Microsoft compiler in the tool-chain options which went away and I can't seem to get it back with Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools.

I have added the folders to user path and tried launching Eclipse from within the build tools "special" terminal but with no success.

Has anyone managed to achieve compilation within eclipse with the build tools and if yes how is it possible?

P.S.: I deliberately changed from Microsoft Visual Studio to Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools, as the difference in disk size is vast.

Answer (score 0):

I have Eclipse 4.6 Neon. In `Help > Install New software` make sure you installed `C/C++ Visual C++ Support`. Restart Eclipse after installation.
I can see `Microsoft Visual C++` in Toolchains now.